# Struggling to Download Files using Android Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, download

I am struggling to make a simple app to download files of the internet heres my code I have edited a little from another question but I am still getting not responding errors whenever I run my app can any one show me the correction or even a different way?

```
    package com.example.downloading;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import org.apache.http.util.ByteArrayBuffer;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.os.ResultReceiver;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.DownloadManager;
import android.app.IntentService;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button startBtn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        startBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.download_button);
        startBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String url = "my stuff";
                DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));
                request.setDescription("descrition");
                request.setTitle("title");

                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
                    request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
                    request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
                }
                request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "etc.mp3");


                DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                manager.enqueue(request);

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void DownLoadTheMusic(){
        try {
            URL url = new URL("http://www.tagsinfosoft.com/android/shelf/Shelf_Cam.mp3");
            HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            c.setRequestMethod("GET");
            c.setDoOutput(true);
            c.connect();

            String PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/download/";
            File file = new File(PATH);
            file.mkdirs();
            File outputFile = new File(file, "Shelf_Cam.mp3");
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);

            InputStream is = c.getInputStream();

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int len1 = 0;
            while ((len1 = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                fos.write(buffer, 0, len1);
            }
            fos.close();
            is.close();


        } catch (IOException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Update error!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }  


call this in a Asynctask




    public class downloadMusic extends AsyncTask<Integer, Integer, Integer>
        {


            @Override
            protected Integer doInBackground(Integer... params) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                try {

                    DownLoadTheMusic();

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                return null;

            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onPostExecute(result);
                Context context=shelf.this;
                pd.dismiss();
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/download/" + "Shelf_Cam.mp3")), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
                startActivity(intent);  

            }

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onPreExecute();
                pd=ProgressDialog.show(shelf.this,"Updating","Please wait....." );
            }

        }
```

execute this task onbutton click use this if you are downloading small music file from internet.

Comment: im trying to use your code and implement it but still no success zny other ideas?